# How to source all vim files in directory

Tags: vim

I have split my .vimrc into several files and placed them into `~/vimfiles/vimrc.d/`.

Currently I source each file in that directory using exact name:

```
source ~/vimfiles/vimrc.d/file1.vim
source ~/vimfiles/vimrc.d/file2.vim
```

etc.

How to make a loop thourgh all files in that directory so i could only have to do such loop in my .vimrc:

```
for file in ~/vimfiles/vimrc.d/*.vim
   source file
enfor
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

As [mb14](https://stackoverflow.com/users/376113/mb14) has already said, if you put them in `~/.vim/plugin` they will be sourced automatically.  For information, however, if you want to source all of the files in your vimrc.d directory, you could do this (requires a relatively recent Vim):

```
for f in split(glob('~/vimfiles/vimrc.d/*.vim'), '\n')
    exe 'source' f
endfor
```

You may also be interested in the autoload mechanism, described in [`:help 41.15`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html#41.15): if you're defining a lot of functions, this can make start-up a bit quicker as the functions are only loaded the first time they're used.

Answer (score 28):

You can just put your files in the plugins directory (~/.vim/plugin). They will be automatically loaded.

Comment: Note: the file should have the extension ```.vim```

Answer (score 16):

mb14 gave you the best answer. You want something automatically executed? Then use the standard organization: here the plugin/ subdirectory.

Otherwise, `:runtime` would have been your friend:

```
:runtime! vimrc.d/*.vim
```

- `:source` barks when its parameter doesn't exist while `:runtime` silently source nothing.
- `:source` can source only one file while `:runtime!` can source any number of files.
- `:source` takes an absolute pathname, or a pathname relative to the current directory while `:runtime` takes a pathname relative to the `'runtimepath'` option, which shouldn't be a problem as long as you respect vim conventions.

Answer (score 1):

The example from DrAl did not work for me, this is how I achieved it:

```
for fpath in split(globpath('~/.vimrc.d/', '*.vim'), '\n')
  exe 'source' fpath
endfor
```

Answer (score 1):

The following snip is what I use within my **`~/.vimrc`** file to source scripts within the **`~/.vimrc.d/`** directory **and** sub-directories...

```
for f in glob('$HOME/.vimrc.d/**/*.vim', 0, 1)
  execute 'source' f
endfor
```

Check `vim -c ':help glob'` for details about additional `glob` arguments.

**TLDR**

```
glob({expr} [, {nosuf} [, {list} [, {alllinks}]]])      *glob()*
```

- *`{nosuf}`* set to *False* allows 'suffixes' and 'wildignore' options to apply
- *`{list}`* set to *True* causes `glob` to return a list that respects new-lines within file names