# Source more than one file with a keybind command in Vim

Tags: vim

Here's my bind:

```
nnoremap <Leader>L :so $MYVIMRC<CR>:so ~/.vim/after/plugin/*.vim<CR>
```

It worked great right up until I added a second configuration file in the plugin folder. Now I get E77: too many file names from the `:so[urce]` command.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500748/how-to-source-all-vim-files-in-directory) which doesn't really make it obvious how to do it from an command string like in a keybind.

How do I write a loop in a keybind? Must a function be declared?

P.S. the reason I even have any scripts in `.vim/after/plugin/` is because there are certain config commands for certain plugins that must be run after their initializations are run, and plugin load scripts run after vimrc. (so they cant just go in the vimrc).

Comment: I'm curious: what plugins would make that necessary? It sounds a lot like bad design.

Comment: Mostly they are plugins which set highlight styles that I prefer to override. One plugin I can't live without is HiCursorWords, and I have a subtle bgcolor and underline highlight style for it. There is likely a way for me to use links to set them in a way that doesn't get trampled through my vimrc, but I can't be bothered. It's pretty clean and works well, and I can add these `after/plugin/*.vim` scripts to my git repo so I can track the config effortlessly, so I'm happy with it.

Comment: Uuurgh, that's a feature I turn off every time I install an IDE. Don't forget to tick the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: That's funny. It increases my productivity like you wouldn't believe. Bugs from typoes? Thing of the past. Need to figure out what some nasty nasty new code does? easy. painless. Just gotta stop thinking of it as a distraction and start thinking of it as revealing how programs are connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:source` takes only one argument but you can use the `:runtime` command:

```
runtime! after/plugin/*.vim
```

which is almost exactly the second example given under `:help :runtime`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also chain the commands together, and it's not as nice as romainl's answer but you can break out into terminal and run source there.

```
nnoremap <Leader>L :so $MYVIMRC|:!source `find ~/.vim/after/plugin/ -name "*.vim"`<CR>
```